# Is it legal and ethical to make a purchase for an institution using a personal credit card and keep the cashback?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, reimbursement

If I purchase a product that costs $100 for an institution using my personal credit card and the institution reimburses me with $100 after the purchase. Later my credit card company gives me $5 cashback for this purchase.

My question: Do I have any moral or legal obligation to give the $5 cashback to the institution? Or can I keep it for myself?

Comment: What does your reimbursement agreement say?

Comment: My company has rules on what things (airfare, hotel) I _must _ put on the company travel card. Beyond those I can use my personal card for other reimbursables.

Comment: @littleadv, I do not find any clearly stated agreement. Basically, the idea is "you make the purchase first and we will reimburse you later".

Comment: @Zuriel then don't ask questions you don't want to hear answers to. Looking by your name, I'm sure you heard of "kitbag questions"...

Comment: @littleadv, I am a bit confused by your comment; Iam ready to accept any honest and reasonable answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is ethical: if your company forced you to use your own card, then all the payments came out of your account, you were at risk if the company suddenly went bankrupt. So it is absolutely appropriate that all benefits for using a card go to you. They are paid for using the account, and it is your account.

What is unethical: if you insist on using your card instead of the company card to get that money. Worse, if the limitations of your bank account mean the company’s business is affected by your refusal. Like an important purchase gets delayed until you have enough money to run it through your bank account.

Comment: Thank you! In my case, the company does not seem to care if I use my card or not. They let me make the choice.

Comment: That’s the case I missed :-) in practise, taking five pound off you costs probably more to handle the accounting side than it is worth.

Comment: You do not only carry the risk of the company going bankrupt, you also carry the risk of something going wrong with the purchase (something wrong with the invoice? => no reimbursement. Of course that means the item is yours, but did you want it for private use?).

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the corporate policy.  I have worked for some that didn't care if I used my personal card to pay for airfare etc. I have worked for some that didn't provide a company card so I had to use my personal card. Others required all travel to be done with a corporate card.

Purchasing items can be a different set of requirements. Some companies want to use their preferred vendors to take  advantage of discounts, so they don't allow employees to directly buy an item. They also want to make sure that you are getting multiple quotes.

Decades ago there was great debate about airline miles and cash back. Did they belong to the company? Did they belong to the employee? Were they considered income? It has been a long time since the company made a claim on the miles/cash back.

The company could become concerned if it appears that you are forcing purchases to be done with your card, thus slowing procurement because of your low credit limit on your card. They also want to make sure the items are really needed.